# How to output a multidimensional array slice

Tags: multidimensional-array, system-verilog

Let's say I have a multidimensional array:

```
logic [7:0] mda [7:0];
```

What I'm now trying to do, is assigning `mda[7:4]` to an output port, i.e. defined as follow:

```
output [31:0] odata;
```

Of course, I can do it by using concatenation:

```
assign odata = {mda[7], mda[6], mda[5], mda[4]};
```

But there should be (and probably is) an easier way to do this. The first try would be:

```
assign odata = mda[7:4];
```

which is wrong, because types (unpacked <-> packed array) don't match. All my tries of casting (e.g. `32'(mda[7:4])`) failed. Question is: what is the best way to assign that slice to an output port?

Comment: Why don't you just use a packed array to describe your multi-dimensional array?  What are the advantages of using unpacked in your situation and does this outweigh the benefits of packed arrays?

Comment: @Chiggs: you can find a lot of tutorials which describe mda as unpacked array. That made me simply curious how to deal with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a for loop... Most synthesis tools have no trouble with for loops over constant ranges:

```
module dut(output [31:0] odata);

  logic [7:0] mda [7:0];  

  reg[31:0] data;
  always @* begin
    data = 0;
    for(int i=7; i >=4; i--) begin
      data <<= 8;
      data |= mda[i];
    end
  end

  assign odata = data;

endmodule
```

Here's a quick test: http://www.edaplayground.com/x/GfM

Answer (score 3):

You can use the streaming operator:

```
initial begin
  logic[31:0] data;

  mda[7] = 'hde;
  mda[6] = 'had;
  mda[5] = 'hbe;
  mda[4] = 'hef;
  data = { >> { mda[7:4] }};

  $display("data = ", data);
end
```

This works perfectly in a procedural context, but not in a continuous assignment context (for some reason). This means this doesn't work:

```
assign odata = { >> { mda[7:4] }};
```

You'll have to figure out a workaround here where you do the streaming in a procedural context (maybe some `always` block) and then assign the result to your wire.

Comment: It seems that constructs of type `always @(mda)` are not allowed, because `mda` is a memory and only scalars are allowed in the sensitivity list. This also applies to `always_comb` blocks. If you try to do any assign based on `mda[7:4]` it will not create an entry in the implicit sensitivity list, whereas an assign based on `mda[7]` will.

Comment: Note that (annoyingly) streaming operators are not supported by many synthesis tools...